# Replace underscore with minus recursively but only for certain extensions?

Tags: rename, file-rename

I want to replace all underscores with a minus for files in a folder and its subfolders and I want to include only jpg, JPG and png. For a start I tried `rename '/_/-/g' ./*` but that does not include subfolders. How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globstar allows you to match files anywhere in a folder or under it. `${f//_/-}` is a bash "Pattern substitution": it replaces the value of `$f`, the double slashes before the pattern mean replace all matches.

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.jpg **/*.JPG **/*.png
do
  mv "$f" "${f//_/-}"
done
```

My system does not support this syntax of `rename`, so I can't give you good advice in its use, but you might also be able to use globstar to generate filenames for it.

Comment: Tested it and wit works just fine on my system ... what does the `shopt -s globstar` exactly do?

Comment: From `man shopt`: "`globstar`: If set, the pattern `**` used in a pathname expansion context  will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by a `/`, only directories and subdirectories match." The `-s` just means "set these options".

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you can traverse the folders with "find":

find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec #rename command here, current filename is "{}"# \;

Edit: Forgot the \;

Comment: You can't easily convert underscores into dashes in `{}`. It's much easier to do it with `for f in $(find . -print ...}`.

Comment: I tried with `find . -type f \( -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.png \) -exec rename 's/_/-/g' {}`, but it keeps saying a parameter for exec is missing?